# how to access stage object out of start method

Tags: javafx, fxml, stage

```
public class grandParent extends Application {
    public Stage primaryStageClone = null;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStageClone = primaryStage;
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("searchBar.fxml"));
        final Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        primaryStageClone.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStageClone.setScene(scene);
        primaryStageClone.setHeight(600);
        primaryStageClone.show();
//primaryStageClone working here....
    }

    public void keyPressedHandler() {
        System.out.println("Now in keyPressedHandler()");
        try{
            primaryStageClone.setHeight(600);//Unable to access here ....It gives exceptions...
        }catch(Exception e){
            primaryStageClone.setHeight(600);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have the problem to access the object out of the start().. I want to access it in keyPressedHandler()... i'm new in javafx help me to figure out my mistake ... thanks

Comment: Are you using your `Application` subclass as your controller? If so, don't.

Comment: No i have different controller ...

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `keyPressedHandler()` then? And also post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not how to access the stage object outside the `start()` method, but how to call `keyPressedHandler()` correctly. Make sure that the reference to it in the controller is not null.

Without the FXML file and its controller, the code looks like shown below and works.

```
public class GrandParent extends Application {

public Stage primaryStageClone = null;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStageClone = primaryStage;
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

     Button b = new Button();
     b.setText("Resize Stage");
     root.getChildren().add(b);
     b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            keyPressedHandler();
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public void keyPressedHandler() {
    System.out.println("Now in keyPressedHandler()");
    primaryStageClone.setHeight(200);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here

    launch(args);
}
```

}